# New build won't boot to BIOS, continuous sets of 3 long beeps

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, bios

I have an ASRock z87, with 1 stick of 8GB ram, GTX 770 GPU, a corsair hx750 PSU and an i5 3.4ghz processor, all of which are connected properly. 
Every time I boot from replugging my PSU in, it boots shuts off then restarts and does the 3 beeps over an over again. Otherwise just using the power button gives the 3 beeps over and over again with no restart. 
There is a red light that is constantly on its called BIOS_A_LED1.

I've booted without my GPU, reseated my RAM to each of the slots to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Look up what that BIOS LED indicates.

Comment: @ekaj oh it just indicates which bios is active atm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual meaning depends on which BIOS the AsRock uses, but three beeps seems to be clearly a memory error.  If your BIOS is AMI, then it's a base 64K memory error; if it's an AWARD BIOS, then it's a general memory error.  If it were an IBM BIOS, it would be a keyboard error, but that's ancient history by now.

For reference: [Beep codes](http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm)

Comment: Hmm, whats the difference between 64k and general memory error? Does this mean my RAM went bad? Does it matter if I boot it without RAM and the same code happens?

Comment: Thank you, it was a bad stick of ram, I replaced it and its not making anymore beeping

Comment: For the original Intel x86 architecture, the first 64K of memory was special, which is why the beep codes have a special code for it.  These days, you just swap the entire stick (as you did).  Glad it was that easy.

Comment: Hi, i'm experiencing the same issue and have 2 x 4GB sticks of RAM. I tried just switching between 1 stick as well as different slots. Could the 3 beeps mean the slots on my motherboard are bad?

Comment: It could be the motherboard, or it could be that both sticks of RAM were damaged by something like a power surge or static shock - they're connected together on a lot of pins, so anything that damages one could damage both.  At this point, you'll need either more components or more tools to isolate the problem.